# How is PL/Python code executed by Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpython

When a PL/Python procedure is executed, the python code is executed by a Python interpreter. My question is, is the Python interpreter running as a separate process, or is it a shared library that gets linked to the calling databases process?

I'm concerned about what happens when we call something like plpy.execute(...). If the python interpreter is running as a separate process I imagine there would be a lot of overhead involved in passing the result of the sql query back to the python interpreter, which would require reading from a file or pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The language handler function (`plpython3_call_handler()`) loads the `plpython3.so` library into the PostgreSQL process, which is linked to `libpython3.so`. So the interpreter is loaded into the backend, it is *not* executed as a separate process (multiprocessing/multithreading is not allowed in PostgreSQL client backends, with the exception of parallel workers).

Comment: Thanks that answers my question. Are there other sources of overhead when using PL/Python other than those specific to executing python code in the first place?

Comment: There is always overhead. Every function call is overhead, and there is definitely an overhead in loading and initializing the Python interpreter the first time you call a PL/Python function in a database session.

Comment: I played around with PL/Python a bit and I can see executing queries from within pl/python functions is particularly slow. Makes me wonder how data is passed between the backend and python interpreter. I posted a separate question if you are willing to look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73657548/calling-plpy-execute-in-pl-python-much-slower-than-calling-execute-in-pl-pgsql